# How to bind checkbox, combobox and radiobutton to settings value in ".setting" file in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, settings

How to bind checkbox, combobox and radiobutton to their respective settings value in ".setting" file in wpf?
I know how to bind textblock to value in settings file. Here is the code

```
<TextBox Margin="5,38,5,2" Width="100" Height="50"  Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Name,    Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: CheckBox is the same, only for `IsChecked` instead of `Text` property, and for a `Boolean` field in your `.settings` file. for the rest you can use [Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a more generic, decoupled solution would be to have wrapping properties in your `ViewModel` and bind it to them instead directly to your `.settings` file.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
```

And in the `ViewModel`

```
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return Settings.Default.IsCheckedVal;
        }
        set
        {
            Settings.Default.IsCheckedVal = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsChecked);
        }
    }
```

Do the same for `ComboBox` and `RadioButton` values.
If you need to bind a `ComboBox` or the `RadioButton` to an enum or other types then what they are expecting, you can use [converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

You will also have to use 
                `Settings.Default.Save();` to save your settings either in a general dedicated command or in every property setter - whatever suits your logic best.

Comment: Didn't had the time to upload examples for `ComboBox` and `RadioButton `. If you need me to just say and I'll upload them later tonight ...

Comment: Please give the examples of ComboBox and RadioButton.

Comment: @user2841983 What is the ComboBox and RadioButton's binded to? enums?

Comment: Done! RadioButton's property "ISChecked" is binded to property i.e. a string.